# I can not run in the single `.js` file, if there is the `import xxx from xxx`

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I can not run in the single `.js` file, if there is the `import xxx from xxx`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I use the single file to debug the imported `ts_config`, how can I do this in WebStorm?

---

**EDIT-1**

The configuration choices are bellow:

[image]

Tell me how to do with this?

Comment: node.js? or some other framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are trying to use is part of the `ES Modules` specification.

However, [`ES Modules`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules) are NOT stable in `Node.js` as of version `v9.9.0`, and should not be used in production.
This functionality is under development, and expected to be stable-released with `Node.js v10.0.0`.

Right now, you can do:

```
const ts_config = require('./tsconfig.json);
```

Comment: I want to use the ES module to import, how to do with that?

Comment: Don't, or your app might stop working when node.js is updated.

Comment: I mean whether I can do it in the experimental environment? see my EDIT-1

Comment: Unfortunately, even with ES Modules, you can only use `import x from y` with files with the `.mjs` extension.

Answer (score 1):

You are using older version of `nodejs` and `import` keyword is not supported in v6.6. Please use version 8 or above for `import` keyword to work without using any transpiler like babel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting your tsConfig?

```
export default
{
  // json here...
}
```